# Installing Concorde on M1 Mac Guide for building ANN around TSP Problem

Tags: traveling-salesman

Im looking for a guide to install the Concorde TSP Solver on a M1 Mac. I have looked everywhere and haven't found a solution that worked for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you try and how did it fail? I don't see any major roadblocks when looking at their source-distribution given a basic dev-setup including a c compiler, autotools and make. Maybe autotools / autoconf is (even) less fun on Mac toolchains...